# Get URL from button in Selenium without clicking button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to get the URL from a link in Selenium WITHOUT clicking the link?

I have the element I need to save but can't find any any details associated with its URL. Text etc is all fine but no URL links. I've searched online but very little posts (that I could find anyway) on Stack Overflow etc.

Am I missing a trick here? Is this so simple its not even a question thats asked. I'm using PyCharm if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) for this:

`pip install seleniumbase` then run with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class LinkTest(BaseCase):
    def test_get_link(self):
        self.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653201/get-url-from-button-in-selenium-without-clicking-button")
        href = self.get_link_attribute("Share", "href")
        print("\nThe href: %s" % href)
        if href.startswith("//"):
            link = "http:" + href
        elif href.startswith("/"):
            url = self.get_current_url()
            domain_url = self.get_domain_url(url)
            link = domain_url + href
        else:
            link = href
        print("Full link: %s" % link)
```

Output:

```
The href: /q/75653201
Full link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75653201
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael for this, SeleniumBase is very impressive! I've marked your post as the answer but must confess that I had issues getting PyTest to work in the super tight time constraints I had and ended up using another solution to get around my problem. I'll circle back to SeleniumBase when I have more time to dedicate to it, but again, thanks very much for posting and linking to it.